# Grafana dashboard Table not reacting/updating to global time range filter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Grafana and Prometheus newb here :(.

I'm working on a Grafana Dashboard where one of the panels has the following characteristics:

- **Visualization:** `Table`
- **Format:** `Table` (see image at the bottom left)

What I'm trying to achieve is that the value computed for the column **Value** reacts to the global time range selected at the dashboard level (image top right in red). At the moment, if I change the global time range for the dashboard, that is not reflected in the table panel time series values.

So far, I can only control this (the time range in which the query is applied) by changing the range selector in the query itself (image bottom center in green arrow). E.g. if I change `[2m]` for `[24h]`, the **Value** column results are as expected.

I've looked into the Grafana docs for some variable/macro containing the selected time range in the dashboard (something like `$__timeFilter` for [MySQL Data Source](https://community.grafana.com/t/table-panel-data-not-responding-to-time-range-controls/4527)), but no luck so far. Perhaps a different query might yield the expected result.

The rest of the panels in the Dashboard respond properly to this global time range changes. Those panels have the following characteristics:

- **Visualization:** `Graph`
- **Format:** `Time series`

Anything I might be missing here? Does Grafana support what I'm trying to do?

[image]

**Additional details:**

- **Grafana Docker image tag**: v7.1.1
- **Grafana Helm app version**: v8.4.2
- **indexed_event**: # TYPE indexed_event gauge

Answer (score 0):

Digging deeper, we can find that there's a global built-in variable that can be used in queries named `$__range`. See the **Using interval and range variables** subsection in the [Grafana Prometheus Data source docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable) for more details.

By simply using `$__range` in the query, we can react to the Grafana dashboard global time range filter. The resulting query would be:

```
sum(delta(indexed_event{app="APP_SELECTOR"}[$__range])) by (event_name)
```